# Regular expression to get minutes not seconds

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a bunch of times from apache logs...

```
96.99.193.124 - - [10/May/2012:22:59:29 +0000] 0 "GET / " 200 123 "-" "-"
96.29.193.124 - - [10/May/2012:22:59:56 +0000] 0 "GET / " 200 123 "-" "-"
96.29.193.125 - - [10/May/2012:22:59:56 +0000] 0 "GET / " 200 123 "-" "-"
96.29.193.125 - - [10/May/2012:23:00:00 +0000] 0 "GET / " 200 123 "-" "-"
96.29.193.125 - - [10/May/2012:23:00:00 +0000] 0 "GET / " 200 123 "-" "-"
```

To pull out the date timestamps, I do:

```
sed -e 's;^.*\(\[.*\]\).*$;\1;' inputFileName > outputFileName
```

Which gives me

```
[10/May/2012:22:59:29 +0000]
[10/May/2012:22:59:56 +0000]
[10/May/2012:22:59:56 +0000] 
[10/May/2012:22:59:56 +0000]
[10/May/2012:23:00:00 +0000] 
[10/May/2012:23:00:00 +0000]
```

I would like to drop the seconds part and the square brackets and the seconds and just get:

```
10/May/2012:22:59 
10/May/2012:22:59 
10/May/2012:22:59 
10/May/2012:23:00
10/May/2012:23:00
```

from the original file... 
Any tips?

Comment: try 
`sed -e 's;^.*\(\[(.*)\+\d+\]\).*$;\2;`

Comment: That gives... sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just

```
 echo '96.99.193.124 - - [10/May/2012:22:59:29 +0000] 0 "GET / " 200 123 "-" "-""' \
 | sed 's/^.*\[//;s/ .*$//;s/...$//'
```

**output**

```
10/May/2012:22:59
```

**explanation**

```
       96.99.193.124 - - [10/May/2012:22:59:29 +0000] 0 "GET / " 200 123 "-" "-""'
      ^........pt1.......[                    ...............pt2.................$
                                           :.. (pt3)
```

Each part eliminates one chunk of the excess string

```
 pt1 s/^.*\]\[// 
     match/deletes everything up to the first [. 
     I use to `\[' to escape the normal meaning of that char in sed 
       as the beginning of a character class, i.e. `[a-z]` (for 1 example)
 pt2 s/ .*$//
     match/deletes everything from the first space char to the end of the line
 pt3 s/...$//
     match/deletes the last 3 chars form the end of the line.
```

Recall that in `sed`

1. 's/matchpattern/replacepattern/' with the intitial 's' = substitute, is one of the main tools available.
2. the ^ char in a regex anchors the matching to the beginning of the line
3. the $ char anchors the matching of the regex to the end of the line.

You should execute just pt1,  then add pt2 and then pt3 to easily see what is being achieved.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @shelter can you explain what every character in the regular expression is doing?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
sed -e 's;^.*\[\([^+]*\).*\].*$;\1;'
```

explain:

1- I put the brackets outside of the group
2- and put the +something outside

and it is done.

Comment: Prints the 29s of 2012:22:59:29.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/.*\[\(.*\):.*/\1/' file
```

You can use *greed* to your advantage i.e. `\(.*\):` grabs everything before the last `:`

Comment: or with `-r` switch and less masking: `sed -r 's/.*\[(.*):.*/\1/'`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's;^.*\[\(.\{17\}\).*\].*$;\1;'
```

This version locates the starting bracket, then explicitly includes the next 17 characters (the string of interest) in the extracted group.

Comment: You can simplify (remove many backslashes) with `sed -r`, see here: `sed -re 's;^.*\[(.{17}).*\].*$;\1;'`

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `grep -oP` :

```
grep -oP "\[\K[^\]\[ ]+" FILE
```

If your grep does not have `-P` switch, try `pcregrep`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pattern:

```
\[(\d+/\w+/\d+:\d+:\d+)
```

The bracket is used as an anchor.
The matchers here are very general. For example, the month is captured using `\w+` which will match any word containing letters or digits, but all the matchers combined using this order for that kind of Apache lines give a robust pattern.

You use this pattern on the entire line, and thus don't need to first capture the part within the bracket. Simply capture the eventual data you want.

Comment: grep "\[(\d+/\w+/\d+:\d+:\d+)" inputFileName gives nothing. Note: I am using cygwin for windows.

Comment: There should be a backslash in the beginning, like in my example

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*\[//;s/:.. .*//' infile > outfile
```

Delete before [ and then from blank. Two commands.